# UPDATE ACROSS JOIN SYNTAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get an update statement to function how I need.  I've tried the following with INNER / OUTER LEFT / RIGHT JOINS.  I continue to have records that are not updated in the usertype2 table despite having usertype3 child values. Am I going about this the right way?  Usertype2 and Usertype3 will always have a mat_id parent value, matter is always parent and usertype2 and usertype3 are child records.

```
UPDATE f
SET f.USR1_05_01 = expTot
FROM lntmuid.usertype2 f JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(e.mat_id) AS matId, SUM(CONVERT(money, e.USR1_02_08)) AS expTot 
    FROM TimeMatters.lntmuid.usertype3 e 
    GROUP BY mat_id
)
e ON f.mat_id = e.matId
WHERE f.mat_id = e.matId
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and desired results. It is also unclear what you mean by *child sub records*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the query as:

```
UPDATE f
    SET f.USR1_05_01 = e.expTot
FROM lntmuid.usertype2 f JOIN
     (SELECT e.mat_id, SUM(CONVERT(money, e.USR1_02_08)) AS expTot 
      FROM TimeMatters.lntmuid.usertype3 e 
      GROUP BY mat_id
     ) e
     ON f.mat_id = e.matId;
```

However, your original query should do what you want.

Comment: Yeah I've tried this as well I just end up getting rows in to usertype2 table that don't update with a value.   Sample data has a lot of columns, just a simple foreign key contrainst from from mat_id to sysid.